# Memory leak in another thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I use [SIMPLEFTP](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html) to do ftp request, when I do request in the main thread, every is ok. But when I run the ftp request in another thread with GCD , I get memory leak sometimes:

[image]

I want to know why things are different in different thread and how to fix this?

Comment: send your code we will check it ? we can not solve using this  image !!!

Comment: @parag I am sorry. I feel really worry about the problem. I have reorganized and pasted the question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000185/a-memory-leak-happen-when-doing-ftp-request-in-the-background-thread